# How can I safely step away from my RAID 1 setup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, raid, raid-0

I have about 500 GB of data on two 1TB drives running a mobo hardware RAID 1. I keep running into problems and have decided to back out of all of this and just use the drives like normal HDD's. I want to unpair the drives and have my computer have absolutely no clue that they were every part of a RAID 1 setup. How can I safely do this?

My current thought is to unplug one of the drives, boot up into my RAID bios utility, delete the array (which I am guessing will kill the drive that is currently plugged in), then plug the other drive in and have windows think it is a slave drive. Does this sound right? I have never tried to do this before.

Comment: I would back everything up into another external drive first. I don't remember right know whether RAID 1 does some magic that prevents you from just taking one of the drives and using it as a standalone one, as you want, so just in case, I'd back it up first and then do it the way you say.

Comment: Is it RAID 0 or RAID 1?

Comment: It is RAID 1. I will back everything up to a bus drive that I have laying around and delete the array.